# Why is my javascript only working when the part of the page it acts on is visible in the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drupal

So I am using the slick image slider and everything was working great until I considered what would happen if images of different heights were put in. I then wrote a short piece of js to check which image is the tallest and set the heights of all of them to that height.

```
window.onload = imageSlideChange;

$(window).resize(imageSlideChange);

function imageSlideChange(){
        var tallestImage = $('.slick-slide').first().height();

    $('.slick-slide').each(function(){ //.slick-slide is the class of each image
        if($(this).height() > tallestImage){
            tallestImage = $(this).height();
        }
    });

    $('.slick-slide').each(function(){
        $(this).height(tallestImage);
    }); 
}
```

The weird thing though is the code only runs correctly when the slider is in the browser window. If I scroll to the bottom or top of the page and reload it will only load the images as 1px height. I thought maybe it was the images not being loaded and set the function to only run on `window.load`but beyond that I don't know what could cause this kind of behavior.

When you go to inspect the images they are the correct height. The 1px must be coming from their default height, which means that when the code runs it must be reading their heights as 0. Why???

If it helps this is all happening as drupal serves up the images, so could that be the problem?

Comment: Inspect the live html in browser dev tools when it is off screen for more clues. Too many unknowns without being able to see a [mcve]

Comment: You may set adaptiveHeight: true;